# Smallest packaging of rectangles

Tags: geometry, optimization, rectangles, packing-problem

I'm trying to stack $n$ rectangles with size $a \times b$ to minimize the distance from the origin to the furthest point ($L$).

I attach a couple of images to clarify.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Thanks for you help!

Jorge

Comment: I don't know your problem well.

Comment: I want to pile up rectangles (boxes) in a way that L is the smallest possible (see pictures). The reason I'd like to solve this is because I'll have a machine to go to some boxes from the origin point, and by doing this, I'll minimize the average path (and time) for the machine to travel

Answer (score 0):

A greedy algorithm will work.

It suffices to show that if we have two boxes stack on top of each other, the higher one will have a greater L. Hence we just maintain a priority queue of all the possible locations to put a box, then choose the one with the smallest L, place it and insert the new possible locations into the priority queue.